# How to correctly implement 'layered lighting' with Box2D-Lights

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, box2d

How does one only allow Box2D-Lights to affect one and only one `OrthographicCamera`.

After researching, I found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047541/box2dlights-layering-lights). This answer goes into detail about how to prevent one camera from being lit by the `RayHandler` by blending layers of the FBO object. I'm unsure if this answer will produce the results I require. If it indeed does create the results I require, how can I do so more simply/elegantly.

For example:

[image: Rocket Game Example]

1) In this image you can see ambient light is set to:

```
this.rayHandler.setAmbientLight(new Color(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.25f));
```

2) There is a point light on the far right with purple colour.

4) There is a star background on a different `OrthographicCamera` to the other objects.

When looking at this image, you notice that the stars are brighter near the planet due to the point light casting light on the background. However, I require the inverse. The stars should be brighter when light is not drowning them out. Knowing that the star background is on a different `OrthographicCamera` how can I allow the texture to be completely unaffected by light so the ambient light of the `RayHandler` does not dim them further away from the planet.

The texture used for the stars contains transparency. The black is created using:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
```

Preferably, I would like to be able to simply place cameras into two lists, affected by light and not affected by light. How does I produce the results I require?

I can manage to get the lighting to ignore the star background by rendering it after the `RayHandler` has been updated and rendered, however this obviously causes the star background to be drawn over the top of everything like so:

[image: Rocket Game Example]

After achieving this, I was reminded of the OpenGL depth buffer. I enabled it using `Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, I then attempted to change the z coordinate of the spritebatch used in the camera for the star background by using `SpriteBatch.getTransformMatrix().idt().translate(0f, 0f, -1f)` however after playing with the values of the other sprite batches I can still not get the effect I require.

It is possible that the above method did indeed work, although I am aware that using the depth buffer incorrectly can cause issues with alpha blending? Making it seem like my problem was not fixed because the planet became translucent.